# CSS percentage height transition lags

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<Accordion selected="2">
    <Accordion.Section title="Section 1" id="1">
        Section 1 content           
    </Accordion.Section>
    <Accordion.Section title="Section 2" id="2">
        Section 2 content         
    </Accordion.Section>
    <Accordion.Section title="Section 3" id="3">
        Section 3 content
    </Accordion.Section>
</Accordion>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sm74cgew/17/

In this accordion example, there is a simple height transition from 0 to 100% when you click on an individual panel. Now this works perfectly when you click on your first panel. After that, there's a "lag" as it's transitioning the previous panel back to 0.

First when looking into ReactCSSTransitionGroup the enter/leave seemed like a solution but I don't have DOM elements disappearing/entering here. The height is just adjusting from 0 to 100%.

I still want to have a transition effect but I don't want the odd lag that occurs. Any suggestions?

I'm looking to get it to work just like jQuery's slideup/down http://jsfiddle.net/xyfgxvca/

Answer (score 1):

Transitioning the height using CSS could be a little tricky, but you can achieve that using JS & React instead of pure CSS.

1º. Set the initial height of the component

```
getInitialState: function(){
     return {height: 0}
}
```

2º Apply the height to the body of your section and set up a ref

```
<div style={{height: this.state.height}} ref="body" className="body">
```

3º Update the component height when the prop **selected** changes

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps){
         if(nextProps._selected !== this.props._selected){
           if(nextProps._selected){
              this.setState( {
                 height: React.findDOMNode(this.refs.body).scrollHeight
              });
           }
           else{
              this.setState( {
                 height: 0
              });
           }
        }
},
```

[full working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sm74cgew/19/)

Comment: Ah, awesome. Thanks for your help!